# REST API or Java Driver API for Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

What suggestions do you have for creating neo4j API to serve clients, if I already created a neo4j database? It seems there are two sets of API:
1) Rest API: https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/
However, most of the contents on this rest api link are marked as 'deprecated'. Why is that?

2) Java Driver API: https://neo4j.com/developer/java/

Are these two sets of APIs are supposed to chosen for Neo4j users? Any suggestions to use which one is better? Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j [REST API](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) is rather old and lacks many of the features available in the newer [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/), which has been available for some time.

As stated in the REST API documentation:

> The API described in this manual been deprecated and will be removed in Neo4j 4.0. [Cypher](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/) and [procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.5/extending-neo4j/procedures-and-functions/procedures/) should be used instead, either via the [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/), or via Bolt using the official [drivers](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/).